# Сравнить каждый элемент массива с каждый без вложенного цикла

Tags: java, алгоритм, циклы, сложность

Каждый элемент массива нужно сравнивать с каждым. Как в моем случае избавиться от вложенного цикла, ибо из-за него сильно возрастает время исполнения?

```
int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if(towns[i] - towns[j] == d)
                count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Тоесть, мы должны экстросенсорно считать вашу задачу, сделать оптимизацию, и ответить вам на вопрос? А вы не в битву экстрасенсов свой вопрос отправлять хотели? Просто других путей сделать x*x переборов, скорее всего, нету. Вам надо задачу/подход/решение оптимизировать а не циклы.

Comment: Ну типа `for (int i = 0; i<n*n; i++) {if(towns[i%n] - towns[i/n] == d) count++;}` Только на количество сравнений это никак не повлияет...

Comment: А можно хотя бы `j < n` заменить на `j < i`. Работать уже будет вдвое быстрее

Comment: @Regent Он же не на равенство проверяет, а на определённую разность, которая не обязана быть нулевой. Так что надо проверять и так, и эдак.

Comment: Если массив реально большой, рекомендую выполнить сортировку. Тогда можно считать разности только с меньшими элементами, и обрывать внутренний цикл при превышении.

Comment: @Akina надо просто ещё `Math.abs` брать от разности, и от `d` (от `d` это можно сделать разово, перед циклами)

Comment: Вопрос поставлен бессмысленно (классическая "XY проблема"). Если сказано, что "каждый элемент массива *нужно* сравнивать с каждым", значит каждый элемент массива *нужно* сравнивать с каждым. Точка. Ничем тут помочь нельзя, задача решения не имеет. А теперь перестаньте рассказывать нам байки про то, что "нужно сравнивать", а расскажите, что нужно *сделать*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Если** всё сводится к count++; и массив чисел целочисленный и с небольшим диапазоном, то делаем примерно так:

1. Цикл по i. Строим гистграмму нашего массива (т.е. вычисляем каких значений сколько).
2. Цикл по j. towns[i] - towns[j] == d из этого следует towns[i] == towns[j] + d. На первом этапе мы уже посчитали число towns[i]. Т.е. если towns[j]=10; d=2, то towns[i] должно быть 12 - смотрим в массиве гистограмм 12-й элемент и приплюсовываем к общей сумме. Переходим к следующему j

Сложность порядка O(n)

Если нужно вывести пары или числа очень большие, то на первом этапе нужно не гистограмму строить, а (видимо) в словарь писать "значение, индекс" (только словарь должен уметь писать несколько строк с одним и тем же значением). И сложность будет прежняя порядка O(n).

Не требует сортировки массива.

Добавлю: в простом случае можно ещё ускорить. Дли этого на втором шаге мы не используем большой массив. Вся инфа есть в массиве гистограмм. Цикл по i:  count+=histogram[i]*histogram[i+d]

Answer (score 4):

Отсортировать. Записать частичные разности. Идти от первого, пока сумма частичных разностей не станет превышать d. Затем вычесть первую частичную разность и начинать работать дальше с запомненной разностью.

Что-то типа для набора `7 5 9 12 4 8 11` ищем `3`

```
             4   5   7   8   9   11   12
разности:      1   2   1   1   2    1

Этап 1  :      1   3   4- все, найдено, выводим. Далее - 4. Стоп, вычли 1, перешли к
Этап 2  :          2   3   4- нашли, выводим.  Далее - опять 4. Стоп, вычли 2, перешли к
Этап 3  :              1   2   4 - Нашли, выводим. Вычитание, переход к
Этап 4  :                  1   3    4 - Нашли, выводим. Вычитание, переход к
Этап 5  :                      2    3 - Нашли, выводим. Вычитание, переход к
Этап 6  :                           1 - более сравнивать нечего.
```

Итак, найдены 4-7, 5-8, 8-11, 9-12

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Возникает вопрос, не будет ли дольше делать сортировку и вычислять частичные разности еще дольше, чем просто сравнить каждый с каждым?

Comment: Просто так в среднем получается O(N lgN), а не O(N^2) (пожалуй, можно придумать мерзкий случай, когда на каждом ходу надо просчитывать все до конца...). А дальше - естественно, нужно смотреть, в зависимости от задачи. Ясно, что для десятка чисел это особого смысла не имеет...

Comment: Вопрос еще поставлен как "Сравнить каждый элемент с каждым", не смотря на то, что код делает другое. Пока ТС не вернется не понятно, ту ли вообще задачу мы сейчас решаем(если сам ТС понимает, какую задачу он решает :)).

Comment: @lDrakonl Логично :)

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать с помощью подвижного окна. Всего суммарно два прохода массива, но нужна сортировка.

```
int[] towns = new int[]{4  , 5 ,  7 ,  8 ,  9 ,  11 ,  12};
Arrays.sort(towns);
int count = 0;
int d = 3;
int i = towns.length-1;
int j = towns.length-2;
while(!(j==0 && towns[i]-towns[j] < d)){
    if(towns[i]-towns[j] == d) count++;
    if(towns[i]-towns[j] < d) j--;
    else i--;
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/188y7n)

Comment: Второй цикл просто спрятан внутри `frequency`...

Comment: @Harry да, вы правы. Сделал по другому

Answer (score 0):

Простите за небрежность в составлении вопроса:)
Суть задачи заключалась в том, чтобы найти количество пар элементов массива, разность которых равна d.
 
Все свелось к тому, чтобы **заменить вложенный цикл**   на нечто такое:

```
    int j = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        while(a[i] - a[j] > d)
            j++;
        if(a[i] - a[j] == d)
            count++;
    }
```